# telerik kendo chart bind to string

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

I am new to telerik kendo chart I have created a string that is being returned from an ashx page. I want the x Axis to be the date has in the month and year and for each date there will be two box going up to the number.

> Is it the way I am sending the string back from the ashx page?

ASHX.CS Page

```
    string JSON = sb.ToString();

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    context.Response.Write(JSON);

[
    {
    "Date":"2/2018"
    "Images":"199956"
    "ImagesDownloads":"540903"
    },
{
    "Date":"3/2018"
    "Images":"226606"
    "ImagesDownloads":"635068"
    }
]
```

In my JS page

```
var DataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
      read: {
      url: function() {
      return "/URI";
      },
      dataType: "json"
      }
      },

      group: {
      field: "Date"
      },

      sort: {
      field: "Date",
      dir: "asc"
      },

      schema: {
      model: {
      fields: {
      date: {
      type: "date"
      }
      }
      }
      }
      });

      function createChart() {
      $("#chart1").kendoChart({
      dataSource: DataSource,
      legend: {
      position: "bottom"
      },
      series:
        [{
          field: "Images",
          categoryField: "Date",
          name: "Number of Images"
          }, {
          field: "ImagesDownloads",
          categoryField: "Date",
          name: "Number of Images download"
        }],
      categoryAxis: {
      field: 'Date'
      },
      tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      shared: true
      }
      });
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {


      $(document).ready(createChart);
      $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this demo for grouped data bar chart](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/grouped-data). 
This demo also shows you how Kendo supports date formatting on category axis you may use the [API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels#categoryaxislabelsdateformats) for more information.